# ServiceStack AuthenticateAttribute results in null reference exceptions second time unless cookies are deleted

Tags: authentication, servicestack

I am trying to get ServiceStacks Authentication to work on an MVC site. My controllers are like this:

```
  public abstract class ControllerBase : ServiceStackController<AuthUserSession> {
    //TODO: override LoginRedirectUrl  
  }

  public class IndexController : ControllerBase {
    [Authenticate]
    public ActionResult Index() {
      return View();
    }
  }
```

The first time I test the code by starting the site from Visual Studio, a redirect to the /login route is made.

Now if I start the site again from Visual Studio, the null reference exception shown below is thrown, and this happens on every restart until I delete all cookies in my browser.

Looks like an error?

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   ServiceStack.Mvc.ServiceStackController`1.get_UserSession() in C:\src\ServiceStack\src\ServiceStack.FluentValidation.Mvc3\Mvc\ServiceStackController.cs:28
   ServiceStack.Mvc.ServiceStackController`1.get_AuthSession() in C:\src\ServiceStack\src\ServiceStack.FluentValidation.Mvc3\Mvc\ServiceStackController.cs:39
   ServiceStack.Mvc.ExecuteServiceStackFiltersAttribute.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) in C:\src\ServiceStack\src\ServiceStack.FluentValidation.Mvc3\Mvc\ExecuteServiceStackFiltersAttribute.cs:21
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14() +19
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +263
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14() +19
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +191
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +343
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +116
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +37
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +7
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +60
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8970061
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok never mind. The errors I experienced was probably because I had not implemented the login route yet.